# Equal heights of subviews with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, height, equals

Equals heights of Image (square form) and TextOne with paddings. How can I do it without GeometryReader?

I can't use GeometryReader because I use this view as row of List

```
var body: some View {
    return HStack {

        VStack {

            Image(systemName: "name").resizable().frame(width: ???, height: ???)

            Spacer()
        }

        VStack {
            HStack (alignment: .center) {

                Text("TextOne").padding()

                Spacer()

                Text("TextTwo").padding()
            }

            HStack (alignment: .top) {


                Text("TextDownOne").padding()

                Spacer()

                Button(action: { action() }) {
                    Text("ButtonText").padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don*t you use .frame(height:whateveryouwant)?

Comment: Because I have different font sizes for iPad and iPhone. And I want, that size of image=height of text

Comment: It is not clear of what to what you want to align. Would you provide some details, or real demo/scratch?

Comment: Yes, I want to align! As in RelativeLayout in Android. Is it impossible?

Comment: If you want to reply someone in comment use like *@Asperi* in comment otherwise there is no notification. Now... I don't know what is *RelativeLayout in Android* because I don't develop for Android. I asked which subviews you want to have equal, because from your code snapshot it is not clear.

Comment: HStack (alignment: .center) or Text("TextOne").padding() and Image(systemName: "name").resizable()